# Decodable nested item in JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to decode some JSON I am getting from the reddit api.
I want to create an array of objects from the data.
The issue is I want to get the data but it is nested two levels deep.

This is the model

```
struct Moderator: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

Here is the part in my network manager where it is trying to get the correct data. It keeps hitting the catch block:

```
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let moderators = try decoder.decode([Moderator].self, from: data)
        completed(moderators, nil)
    } catch {
        completed(nil, "Invalid data")
    }
```

I am getting the json from here:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/about/moderators.json
```

A sample from it:

```
kind    "UserList"
data    
   children 
      0 
         name   "name3465"
         author_flair_text  null
         date   1297779059
         rel_id "rb_c32nl"
         id "t2_4d9s0"
         author_flair_css_class null
      1 
         name   "name2279"
         author_flair_text  null
         date   1300169101
         rel_id "rb_d151z"
         id "t2_1f8e1"
         author_flair_css_class null
```

Comment: You can’t start in the middle when decoding a json message so you need a root element for UserList to hold your array of Moderator. And don’t ignore the error in the catch, it contains vital information for understanding what goes wrong so print it or send it to the completion handler

Comment: To expand on @JoakimDanielson answer... You'll need a model for the list itself: List will have a `var data: [String : [Moderator]]`. That should help you decode the list model entity. Note, you'll have to access the moderators via `data["children"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example `ModeratorResponse` and `Moderator` would be the struct you wish to use in the app, and `RawModerator` is a private struct that hides the parsing that ignores the nested structures in between the data you are interested. Take a look at this example you can try on [online.swiftplayground.run](http://online.swiftplayground.run/):

```
import Foundation

private struct RawModerator: Decodable {
    struct Data: Decodable {
        var children: [Moderator]
    }

    var kind: String
    var data: Data
}

struct ModeratorResponse: Decodable {
    var moderatorList: [Moderator]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let rawResponse = try RawModerator(from: decoder)
        moderatorList = rawResponse.data.children
    }
}

struct Moderator: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var authorFlairTxt: String?
    var permissions: [String]?
    var date: Double?
    var rel_id: String
    var id: String
    var authorFlairCssClass: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case authorFlairTxt = "author_flair_text"
        case permissions = "mod_permissions"
        case date = "date"
        case rel_id = "rel_id"
        case id = "id"
        case authorFlairCssClass = "author_flair_css_class"
    }
}

let json = """
{
    "kind": "UserList", 
    "data": {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "doug3465", 
                "author_flair_text": null, 
                "mod_permissions": ["all"], 
                "date": 1297779059.0, 
                "rel_id": "rb_c32nl", 
                "id": "t2_4d9s0", 
                "author_flair_css_class": null
            }, 

            {
                "name": "joka86", 
                "author_flair_text": null, 
                "mod_permissions": ["all"], 
                "date": 1571872041.0, 
                "rel_id": "rb_1k9iezh", 
                "id": "t2_36u6d", 
                "author_flair_css_class": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ModeratorResponse.self, from: json) {
    for moderator in results.moderatorList {
        print("ID: \(moderator.id)")
        print("Name: \(moderator.name)")
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID: t2_4d9s0
> Name: Optional("doug3465")
> ID: t2_36u6d
> Name: Optional("joka86")
> ```